# Using the Short Time Format with WinForms' DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string-formatting, datetimepicker

I want a DateTimePicker to display its time using [the standard .NET Short Time Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortTime), but the "Custom" option for the DateTimePicker [doesn't take the standard format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx).

Is there any way to get the equivalent custom format string for the DateTimePicker from the current culture (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
```

Or

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
```

Comment: Any reason I shouldn't go with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern`? It's shorter and appears to do the same thing.